# Touchscreen on Raspberry Pi emits click not touch

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen

i  folowed this link to calibrate touchscreen: http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-calibration-screen-rotation/.

```
ls -la /dev/input/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     240 Jul 12 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root    3460 Jul 12 18:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Jul 12 18:38 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Jul 12 18:38 by-path
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 64 Jul 12 18:38 event0
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 65 Jul 12 18:38 event1
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 66 Jul 12 18:38 event2
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 67 Jul 12 18:38 event3
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 68 Jul 12 18:38 event4
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 63 Jul 12 18:38 mice
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 32 Jul 12 18:38 mouse0
crw-rw----  1 root input 13, 33 Jul 12 18:38 mouse1

root@raspberrypi:/sys/devices/virtual/input# cat input4/uevent 
PRODUCT=0/0/0/0
NAME="FT5406 memory based driver"
PROP=2
EV=b
KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ABS=2608000 3
MODALIAS=input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,3,k14A,ra0,1,2F,35,36,39,mlsfw

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/ts.conf
# Uncomment if you wish to use the linux input layer event interface
module_raw input

# Uncomment if you're using a Sharp Zaurus SL-5500/SL-5000d
# module_raw collie

# Uncomment if you're using a Sharp Zaurus SL-C700/C750/C760/C860
# module_raw corgi

# Uncomment if you're using a device with a UCB1200/1300/1400 TS interface
# module_raw ucb1x00

# Uncomment if you're using an HP iPaq h3600 or similar
# module_raw h3600

# Uncomment if you're using a Hitachi Webpad
# module_raw mk712

# Uncomment if you're using an IBM Arctic II
# module_raw arctic2

module pthres pmin=1
module variance delta=30
module dejitter delta=100
module linear
```

I only get response when configuring X with xinput_calibrator. When i enter this command

```
sudo TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0 TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1 ts_calibrate
```

I get optput

```
xres = 800, yres = 480
selected device is not a touchscreen I understand
```

Can someone please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this, but I believe that it is related to the problem of touches being treated as mouseovers. This bug has been reported several times, but never actually fixed

```
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/945
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789041
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1792787
```

A bugzilla.gnome.org user named niteshgupta16 created a script that solves this problem, but it was uploaded to pasting/sharing service called hastebin at https://www.hastebin.com/uwuviteyeb.py.

Hastebin deletes files that have not been accessed within 30 days. Since hastebin is a javascript-obfuscated service, this file is not available on archive.org.

I am unable to find an email for niteshgupta16 in order to ask him if he still has uwuviteyeb.py.